# c++ How to evaluate a list of functions?

Tags: c++, lambda, functional-programming

I am creating a c++ library allowing users to evaluate a list of functions. For example, user will provide three functions

```
A mapper1(B);
B mapper2(C);
C mapper3(D);
```

and I will evaluate them against a list of input D, retrieving a list of A.

The function list is provided by the user. It is known at compile-time, but not known to me. How do I implement this, e.g., what data structure should I use to maintain the function list?

The user provides the functions using a template API:

```
template <typename T>
class Mapper {
public:
    unique_ptr<Mapper<N>> map(function<N(T)>);
}
```

Comment: Just to be sure, you want something like this: 
`Mapper m{
      [](auto v) { return v * v; },
      [](auto v) { return 2 * v; },
  };
  auto result = m(1,2,3);
  // result should be : 2, 4, 6 => 4, 16, 36`

Comment: @ElvisOric Yes that is what I want

Answer (score 0):

you can use std::list of command type , making functions of command type defined at link

http://www.vincehuston.org/dp/command.html

Summarising contents below:

1. Define a Command interface with a method signature like execute().
2. Create one or more derived classes that encapsulate some subset of the following: a "receiver" object, the method to invoke, the arguments to pass.
3. Instantiate a Command object for each deferred execution request.
4. Pass the Command object from the creator (aka sender) to the invoker (aka receiver).
5. The invoker decides when to execute().

Example is attached herewith:

```
class Giant {
public:
   Giant()       { m_id = s_next++; }
   void fee()    { cout << m_id << "-fee  "; }
   void phi()    { cout << m_id << "-phi  "; }
   void pheaux() { cout << m_id << "-pheaux  "; }
private:
   int  m_id;
   static int s_next;
};
int Giant::s_next = 0;

class Command {
public:
   typedef void (Giant::*Action)();
   Command( Giant* object, Action method ) {
      m_object = object;
      m_method = method;
   }
   void execute() {
      (m_object->*m_method)();
   }
private:
   Giant* m_object;
   Action m_method;
};

template <typename T>
class Queue {
public:
   Queue() { m_add = m_remove = 0; }
   void enque( T* c ) {
      m_array[m_add] = c;
      m_add = (m_add + 1) % SIZE;
   }
   T* deque() {
      int temp = m_remove;
      m_remove = (m_remove + 1) % SIZE;
      return m_array[temp];
   }
private:
   enum { SIZE = 8 };
   T*  m_array[SIZE];
   int m_add, m_remove;
};

int main( void ) {
   Queue que;
   Command* input[] = { new Command( new Giant, &Giant::fee ),
                        new Command( new Giant, &Giant::phi ),
                        new Command( new Giant, &Giant::pheaux ),
                        new Command( new Giant, &Giant::fee ),
                        new Command( new Giant, &Giant::phi ),
                        new Command( new Giant, &Giant::pheaux ) };

   for (int i=0; i < 6; i++)
      que.enque( input[i] );

   for (int i=0; i < 6; i++)
      que.deque()->execute();
   cout << '\n';
}

// 0-fee  1-phi  2-pheaux  3-fee  4-phi  5-pheaux
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Neither the functions nor their return types are known to me. They are lambdas provided by the user. Also I have tried the command approach. As I have a large number of objects to evaluate, creating many command objects can bring overheads. So I am looking for ways to "directly" execute functions.

Comment: Just edited the answer to include abstract for future

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proof of concept, you can better adapt it for your need. I defined mapper as a function.

```
template <typename T>
std::vector<T> helper(std::vector<T> vec) {
  return vec;
}

template <typename T, typename Fun>
std::vector<T> helper(std::vector<T> vec, Fun fun) {
  std::vector<T> result;
  for (const auto& v : vec) {
    result.emplace_back(fun(v));
  }
  return result;
}

template <typename T, typename Fun, typename... Funs>
std::vector<T> helper(std::vector<T> vec, Fun fun, Funs... funs) {
  return helper(helper(vec, funs...), fun);
}

template <typename T, typename... Funs>
std::vector<T> mapper(std::vector<T> vec, Funs... funs) {
  return helper(vec, funs...);
}

int main() {
  auto result = mapper(
      std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3},
      [](auto v) { return v * v; },
      [](auto v) { return 2 * v; }, 
      [](auto v) { return v + 1; });

  for (const auto& v : result) {
    std::cout << v << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Note: 
If you need different ordering, replace

```
return helper(helper(vec, funs...), fun);
```

with:

```
return helper(helper(vec, fun), funs...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your mappers have different signatures you need a `tuple` to hold them. And I see no reason to use `std::function` as we don't need its type erasure.

My idea is pretty simple: we store all the mappers in a tuple and we create a recursive call to them. (please note that for the sake of simplicity I don't bother with forwarding. You can add that if you want).

```
template <class... Args>
struct Mapper
{
    std::tuple<Args...> fs;

    Mapper(Args... args) : fs{args...} {}

    template <std::size_t I, class T>
    auto call(T arg)
    {
        if constexpr (I == sizeof...(Args))
            return arg;
        else
            return call<I + 1>(std::get<I>(fs)(arg));
    }

    template <class T>
    auto operator()(T arg)
    {
        return call<0>(arg);
    }
};
```

Example usage:

```
auto test()
{
    auto mapper = Mapper{mapper3, mapper2, mapper1};

    D d{};
    A a = mapper(d);
}
```